# How to Set up Activeflag if we have CorpFlag?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

In my c# code I am using corpFlag to get the values 1 or 0 in one of my columns. But now I want Y N values in my column instead of 1 and 0. How to write c# code for active Flag?

My c# code for corpFloag is:

```
 if (dtGridNwBrandModel.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[10].Value.ToString().ToLower() == "false")
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = false;
  }
   else
  {
     chk_CorpFlag.Checked = true;
  }
```

Comment: What is your datasource? Are you expecting `Y/N` on the cell instead a checkbox?

Comment: I would check Example2 here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Kaf:yes i nedd Y or N instead of check box